# Flow runs also if I update/create related object

Tags: visual-workflow

I created a record-triggered flow which runs if the record is created or updated from my custom object (contract). This works fine so far.
But yesterday I uploaded new data (sales), which are related to my custom object (contract), and the flow triggered also, can I deactivate this function?
Because the flow should run just when I upload or create records from my custom object (contract).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a related object uses a Trigger, Flow, Process, or Rollup Summary field, and the record changes as a result, the Record-Triggered Flow will also trigger. The only way to avoid this is to not rollup or modify the parent object in any way.

Comment: I upload new data of sales, which have only a relationship to the contract, not more. I update not the contract data and the flow is triggered by update/create contract. Is that correct?

Comment: @peXeq I'm not sure I understand your comment. As I said in my answer, though, the Flow would only trigger if the Contract were somehow updated. You might want to read [Triggers and Order of Execution](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm) for more information on the save process.